# How to create a horse-shoe-like gauge using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to draw a horse-shoe like gauge using CSS like the following picture below:

[image: horse-shoe-gauge]

The way I've tried is doing something like creating a circle and cutting off the bottom like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fz3Ln/12/

markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="horse-shoe-gauge"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horse-shoe-gauge {

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    border: 10px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But I'm not able to get the circular rounded bottom.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Frankly, I'd go with SVG rather than make complicated shapes with messy extra divs & CSS.

Comment: I wish people would stop trying to force CSS to do these kinds of tricks that it's just not designed for. You've got a perfectly good tool for creating things like this called SVG; use that instead. The only reason for avoiding SVG is if you need to support old browsers that don't support it... but in that case, you'd be lacking the CSS features you need as well anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something a bit different with `:before` and `:after` so that the html doesn't need to be modified.

I would however probably consider using `canvas` instead as it will give more control.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fz3Ln/16/

```
.horse-shoe-gauge:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 12px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border: 15px solid white;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    background-color: black;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
}

.horse-shoe-gauge:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    right: 12px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border: 15px solid white;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    background-color: black;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
}
```

To see how it's working, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz3Ln/17/).

Answer (score 2):

I added an outer container and then absolutely position a couple extra pieces to get the rounded bottoms you were looking for.

**HTML**

```
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="horse-shoe-gauge"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom left"></div>
    <div class="bottom right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outerContainer {
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.horse-shoe-gauge {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    border: 10px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #000;
}
.left {
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 38px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(32deg);
}
.right {
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 137px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-32deg);
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/a9Nx2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

http://codepen.io/robcampo/pen/YXpWLP

Should work from IE10+. It essentially rotates two divs beside each other and uses markers to round out the edges:

```
<div class="radial-wrapper">
  <div class="radial-section radial-right-section">
    <div class="wedge"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="radial-section radial-left-section">
    <div class="wedge"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="marker start"></div>
  <div class="marker end"></div>
</div>
```

It may be somewhat hard to read but it originates from this tutorial:

https://cssanimation.rocks/watch/

which goes through each step.